# How to implement a tab generator with interactive buttons?

Tags: bokeh

My app has a button for creating new tabs. Each new tab has itself a button. When I add `on_click` to that button I get a error handling message:

> error handling message Message 'EVENT' (revision 1) content: '{"event_name":"button_click","event_values":{"model_id":"1002"}}': RuntimeError('Set changed size during iteration',)

Here is a minimal example that causes the error message.

```py
from bokeh.models import Panel, Tabs, Button
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc

def print_stuff():
    print('stuff')

def create_new_tab():

    button = Button(label='click me')
    button.on_click(print_stuff)
    tab = Panel(child=button, title="tab")

    return tab

def append_new_tab():
    new_tab = create_new_tab()
    curdoc().select_one({'name': 'tabs'}).tabs.append(new_tab)

button = Button(label='append new tab')
button.on_click(append_new_tab)

tab1 = Panel(child=button, title='button tab')
tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab1], name='tabs')

curdoc().add_root(tabs)
```

My questions are:

1. Which set changes during iteration?
2. During what iteration?
3. How to fix this?

Background:
Tab 1 is a configuration tab with several input widgets. The `append new tab` button creates a tab with several data plots that are generated using the input widgets. These plots have themselves buttons.

Answer (score 1):

It is [a bug](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8835) that should have been fixed in Bokeh v1.1.1

Comment: I can not find `v1.1.1` in https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/ Are you saying it will be fixed in the next version?

Comment: v1.1.1 is a [development version](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/dev/docs/user_guide.html) (has not been released yet)